# upload doc, docx, pdf files on server using php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload

I wish to upload documents having extensions doc, docx and pdf on server. for this i used the following code but i am not able to upload the files

```
<?php
if($_POST['save'])
    {

        $target_dir = "reqdoc/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (file_exists($target_file)) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
            {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if($imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, only doc, docx, pdf";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            } 
        else 
            {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
                    {
                        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
            }
    }
?>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

i got the error saying

```
Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, only doc, docx, pdfSorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

can anyone please tell where the code went wrong

Comment: use if..elseif..else

Comment: Add the `enctype='multipart/formdata'` to your form, a hidden field called `MAX_FILE_SIZE` with the size, in bytes, as the value - these should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

you are miss 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in your form

you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use multipart/form-data when your form includes any  elements.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html

```
<?php
if($_POST['save'])
    {

        $target_dir = "media/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (file_exists($target_file)) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
            {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if($imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, only doc, docx, pdf";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
            {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            } 
        else 
            {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
                    {
                        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
            }
    }
?>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.